# Zend OpCache showing in phpinfo() but isn't doing anything

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm running a VPS environment with PHP 5.3.27. Installed and configured Zend Opcache but it's not actually caching anything. The only file it is caching is the Opcache monitor.

```
0% memory usage
0% hit rate
total memory: 128.000MB
used memory: 276.266KB
free memory: 127.730MB
wasted memory: 0.000 bytes (0%)
number of cached files: 1
number of hits: 0
number of misses: 1
blacklist misses: 0
number of cached keys: 1
max cached keys: 7,963
```

Here's the config (PHP -v):

```
PHP 5.3.27 (cli) (built: Jan 25 2014 16:33:43)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies
```

Zend OPcache (phpinfo)

```
> Opcode Caching    Up and Running Optimization Enabled Startup OK Shared
> memory model  mmap Cache hits 0 Cache misses  1 Used memory   225752 Free
> memory    133991976 Wasted memory 0 Cached scripts    1 Cached keys   1 Max
> keys  7963 OOM restarts   0 Hash keys restarts    0 Manual restarts   0
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value opcache.blacklist_filename no
> value no value opcache.consistency_checks 0   0 opcache.dups_fix  Off Off
> opcache.enable    On  On opcache.enable_cli   On  On
> opcache.enable_file_override  Off Off opcache.error_log   no value    no
> value opcache.fast_shutdown   1   1 opcache.file_update_protection    2   2
> opcache.force_restart_timeout 180 180 opcache.inherited_hack  On  On
> opcache.load_comments 1   1 opcache.log_verbosity_level   1   1
> opcache.max_accelerated_files 4000    4000 opcache.max_file_size  0   0
> opcache.max_wasted_percentage 5   5 opcache.memory_consumption    128 128
> opcache.optimization_level    0xFFFFFFFF  0xFFFFFFFF
> opcache.preferred_memory_model    no value    no value
> opcache.protect_memory    0   0 opcache.restrict_api  no value    no value
> opcache.revalidate_freq   60  60 opcache.revalidate_path  Off Off
> opcache.save_comments 1   1 opcache.use_cwd   On  On
> opcache.validate_timestamps   On  On
```

Comment: I got the exact same problem.

opcache is running but is caching only one file : op.php.
My server is debian wheezy running with sbox_copy

Comment: How is PHP executed? If as CGI then opcache won't really work as separate process is created for every request and each of them starts with their own, empty opcache.

Answer (score 0):

There is something rare in :

```
number of cached files: 1
number of hits: 0
number of misses: 1
```

It says that you are cached only 1 file.  May be PHP had restarted at some point or it is creating different proccess

Answer (score 0):

I used to experience this situation.
I tried to restart php-fpm and opcache worked again.